# How to preload images in angular4 without adding to DOM?

Tags: angular, angular5

I am working on an application which has lot of large sized images and their urls are dynamic. If I load all of them to DOM and hide/show the required that makes the page really slow. I want to load the images in the background without making the DOM slow. Does any body have some tips or solutions pls. Thanks in advance